# Equivalent in java 8 from guava Enums.getIfPresent() that will return java.util.Optional?

Tags: java-8, guava, option-type

I have the following code from an old group that is using guava Optional and Enums (getIfPresent).

```
// getNameAsString returns the string literal but I want to safely convert
// to an enum and return an java.util.Optional <MessageName>.
// MessageName is an enum
Optional<MessageName> msgName = Enums.getIfPresent(MessageName.class, obj.getMessage().getNameAsString());
```

How can I convert this to java 8? What is the equivalent of guava Enums.getIfPresent in java 8 that would return an java.util.Optional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fake it with Java 8 as follows

```
import java.util.Optional;
Optional<MessageName> msgName = getValueOf(MessageName.class,obj.getMessage().getNameAsString());

 public static Optional<MessageName> getValueOf(Class<MessageName> enumType, String name){
            MessageName enumValue = null;
                    try{enumValue =Enum.valueOf(enumType, name);
                        }catch(IllegalArgumentException ex ){
                            //log this here
                        }
            return Optional.ofNullable(enumValue);
        }
```

The static method `getValueOf` deals with `IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: sorry for not being clear....i changed the getName to getNameAsString()....because it's being returned as a string and I want to convert an enum....like the guava method is doing (see edits above)

Comment: So you are quoting the part of the documentation which clearly says that the result will never be `null` (as the method will throw an exception for wrong names) but still think attempting to wrap the result via `ofNullable` was a solution?

Comment: It was to point out that very point, so in real code youhave to deal with it, either wrapping Enum.valueOf() into an EnumWrapper, catch the exception and return null or Optional

Comment: have edited the answer to deal with `IllegalArgumentException`

Answer (score 10):

A more `Stream`-idiomatic way with some generics sprinkled on the method signature:

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> Optional<T> valueOf(Class<T> clazz, String name) {
    return EnumSet.allOf(clazz).stream().filter(v -> v.name().equals(name))
                    .findAny();
}
```

To test:

```
enum Test {
    A;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream.of(null, "", "A", "Z").map(v -> valueOf(Test.class, v))
            .forEach(v -> System.out.println(v.isPresent()));
}
```

Expected output:

```
false
false
true
false
```

Comment: I'm surprised the other - exception driven answers were upvoted

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to make a slightly cleaner version of @iamiddy's answer, but unfortunately i can't really put it in a comment, and it might not be OK to edit that answer.

This example is made to point out that there is no benefit in having a temporary value that might be null.

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> Optional<T> getValueOf(Class<T> enumType, String name) {
    try {
        return Optional.of(Enum.valueOf(enumType, name));
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```